# Installing a list of packages in OPAM

Tags: installation, ocaml, package-managers, opam

[OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org/) is a great Package Manager for OCaml.

Is there a way to install a given list of packages like `pip` does in Python (with the command `pip -r requirements.txt`)?

We have a small Git repo shared with several people and it would be nice to just install all project dependencies in one go.

And yes, we might have a little shell script or list the packages in a .txt file and pipe it to `opam install` ... but there might be a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have your dependencies specified in `NAME.opam` (or just `opam`) file in your project, you can run

```
opam install . --deps-only
```

This will install all dependencies for your package (or packages if you have several opam files in your project).

By default opam ignores uncommitted changes, so if you want to run this command with modified opam files you'll need to add `--working-dir`.

Optionally you could lock down versions of dependencies used by running `opam lock`, this will create `.opam.locked` files. `opam-lock` is a separate plugin in 2.0.5 (and likely until 2.1), so opam will prompt to install it.

With lock files present, you should also add `--locked` to `opam install` to ask it to use lock file and install exactly the same versions.

I would also recommend adding `-j X` where `X` is the number of cores you have available, that will speed things up.

I typically have the following in my Makefiles:

```
deps:
        opam install . --deps-only --locked --working-dir
```

The syntax of **.opam** files is described [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Manual.html#Common-file-format)

Comment: Thanks. What is the syntax for `.opam` files?

Comment: I have `opam` version 1.2.2: is it compatible with what you just said? I have the following   `opam: unknown option `--working-dir'.`

Comment: Not sure about 1.2.2, it works for 2.0.5, which is what I have. Why not to upgrade opam? See here for syntax manual: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Manual.html#Common-file-format
A lot of examples on the internets, this one is pretty simple to digest: https://github.com/inhabitedtype/httpaf/blob/master/httpaf.opam

Comment: I might not be able to do it: got message `opam is already the newest version (1.2.2-6).` when trying to upgrade. Maybe because I'm using Ubuntu in a WSL (in Win10) or I am in China and some connections are blocked... anyway, I can live without it. Thanks @Lupus!

Comment: Distros usually ship pretty outdated OCaml infrastructure. I suggest to install latest opam as described [in official manual](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html), and create global/local switch with fresh OCaml.